# Fetching Database Value in <p> tag in PHP, MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch database value in html

tag, is it possible ?? I can fetch database value in textbox using this code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hct_db"); // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// escape variables for security 
$client_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['client_id']);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client where client_id = '" . $client_id . "'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

   <input class="form-control" name="client_id1" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['address'] ) ); ?>" />
```

Comment: how michael please  ?

Comment: lmfgfy http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (it will fill your input boxes with the value)

```
 <?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hct_db"); // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// escape variables for security 
$client_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['client_id']);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM client where client_id = '" . $client_id . "'");

echo '<form action="" method="post">';//openning upthe 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo '<p>'.( htmlspecialchars( $row['address'] ) ).'</p>';
 }
```

Comment: i want to fetch on label or <p> tag not on textbox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. At first, retrieve your data using query and keep it an array and then echo it.

Comment: <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hct_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 
// escape variables for security
$client_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['client_id']);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM client where client_id = '".$client_id."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

this is my retrieve code, what to do next ?

Comment: then add your form and echo data in your form field.just like that - ?> <input class="form-control" name="client_id1" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $row['address'] ) ); ?>" /> <?php }?>

Answer (score 0):

yes you can try this and pls try something before posting a question...

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hct_db"); // Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} // escape variables for security 

$client_id  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['client_id']); 
$result     = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM client where client_id = '".$client_id."'"); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  //this is my retrieve code, what to do next ? ?>
    <a href="#"><? echo $row[0]; ?></a> // href tag
    <h2><? echo $row[0]; ?></h2>    //h tag
    <p><? echo $row[0]; ?></p>  //p tag 
    //and so on
<?}?>
```

comment for further querys...